# How to compare time stamps in log lines that also has version numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, comparison

I am trying to find the version number log line with the most recent time stamp, and I am currently trying to do it by using parse_version.

log line examples:

```
2018-05-08T15:25:02.053Z 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 > LVL:2 RC: version: 2.11.0.10451

2018-05-08T21:27:14.2049217Z> <INFO >: Version: 2.10.0.23960

2018-05-08T21:18:53.0428568Z> <INFO >: Version: 2.12.1.26051
```

Although the last log line has the latest version number, I hope to store and display the second log line even though it has the lower version number because it has the latest time stamp. Currently, using the parse_version comparison I am printing the last log line(I'm guessing because the combined value between time stamp and version is bigger overall).

The below is my current code:

```
                for line in f: #For simplicity sake, I won't include my code above this line because it's just for looping through the folder to find the log lines
                #0strip out \x00 from read content, in case it's encoded differently
                line = line.replace('\x00', '')

                #Regular expressions for finding the log lines in the folder
                RE2 = r"^.+INFO.+Version.+"
                RE3 = r"^.+RC: version"

                latest_version_line = ''
                #Find the general matches, and get the version line with the latest time stamp
                pattern2 = re.compile('('+RE2+'|'+RE3+')', re.IGNORECASE)
                for match2 in pattern2.finditer(line):

                    if parse_version(line) > parse_version(latest_version_line):
                        latest_version_line = line

                print(latest_version_line)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to store and display the second-latest version number, you can simply use another variable to retain the current latest version number before it gets replaced by the new latest version number.

Change:

```
                if parse_version(line) > parse_version(latest_version_line):
                    latest_version_line = line

            print(latest_version_line)
```

to:

```
                if parse_version(line) > parse_version(latest_version_line):
                    second_latest_version_line = latest_version_line
                    latest_version_line = line

            print(latest_version_line)
            print(second_latest_version_line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not necessarily trying to store the second latest version number, those are just examples I've provided and in reality there are thousands of those lines in my folder. I'm trying to find/store/display the line with the latest time stamp. I hope that makes sense?